# PDS member list associated with DDNAME

Tags: cobol, zos

How to get member list of a PDS(using a DD Name specified in a batch job) using a COBOL?
It is possible to dynamically process PDS(es) specified using a DDNAME. So Getting a list of PDS(es) for a given DDNAME and processing a specified member name is possible using TCB.

But how to get member list of PDS  using COBOL? I Know this can be easily implemented using REXX. But I need it in COBOL or directly callable from COBOL.

Comment: You want a list of all the members in a PDS which is specified on a DD statement in the JCL? Or something else?

Comment: It is possibly but why???

Comment: Yes it is. To implement a wrapper of an existing tool to execute it for all members of a dataset instead of a single member of a pds. It is just  additionally providing "-dir"  like option.

Comment: COBOL works (as Bill demonstrates), but you might want to consider LE-compliant assembler or C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you specify this, with a simple SELECT (include FILE STATUS, of course), you will be able to read a PDS directory.

```
   FD  INPUT-FILE 
       RECORDING MODE IS U 
       LABEL RECORDS ARE STANDARD. 
   01  INPUT-RECORD. 
       05  FILLER PIC X(256).
```

In the JCL you specify the DDName like this:

```
//ffffffff DD DISP=OLD,DSN=yourpdsname,
//            RECFM=U,LRECL=256
```

You can also change the RECORDING MODE to F in the COBOL program and the RECFM to F in the JCL. Either will work (U(ndefined) or F(ixed)).

Then you just treat the directory as a normal file.

However, there are multiple entries per directory block, and you'll need to understand those to be able to use the data.

Here's a program originally from about 1982. At some point I changed what was originally a GO TO loop to be an inline PERFORM and made other changes for what was then available as new under IBM's VS COBOL II, to the 1985 COBOL Standard.

EXPANDED-DIRECTORY is a copybook which I've pasted-in for you.

You CALL the program with the input record, as defined above, and the EXPANDED-DIRECTORY.

Then, after each CALL, you have access to the members from the current block (if there are any).

```
   ID DIVISION. 
   PROGRAM-ID. OCDIRBLK. 
   DATA DIVISION. 
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION. 
   01  LENGTH-UP-DIRECTORY          BINARY PIC 9(4). 
   01  LENGTH-OF-USER-DATA          BINARY PIC 9(4). 
   01  DIRECTORY-DATA-LENGTH        BINARY PIC 9(4). 
   01  HIGH-ORDER-BIT-VALUE         BINARY PIC 9(4) VALUE 128.
   01  BIT-ONE-VALUE                BINARY PIC 9(4) VALUE 64. 
   01  BIT-TWO-VALUE                BINARY PIC 9(4) VALUE 32. 
   01  USER-DATA-LENGTH             BINARY PIC 9(4). 
       88  NO-USER-HALFWORDS               VALUE ZERO. 
       88  SOME-USER-HALFWORDS             VALUE 1 THRU 31. 
       88  MEMBER-HAS-ONE-POINTER          VALUE 32 THRU 63. 
       88  MEMBER-HAS-TWO-POINTERS         VALUE 64 THRU 127. 
       88  MEMBER-IS-AN-ALIAS              VALUE 128 THRU 255.
   01  FILLER REDEFINES USER-DATA-LENGTH. 
       05  FILLER                          PIC X. 
       05  USER-DATA-BYTE                  PIC X. 
   LINKAGE SECTION. 
   01  INPUT-DIRECTORY. 
       05  I-D-LENGTH               BINARY PIC 9(4). 
           88  I-D-NO-MEMBERS              VALUE ZERO. 
       05  FILLER OCCURS 0 TO 252 TIMES 
           DEPENDING ON LENGTH-UP-DIRECTORY 
                                           PIC X. 
       05  I-D-MEMBER-NAME                 PIC X(8). 
           88 I-D-END-OF-BLOCK             VALUE HIGH-VALUES. 
       05  I-D-TRACK-ADDRESS               PIC XXX. 
       05  I-D-INDICATOR                   PIC X. 
       05  I-D-USER-DATA. 
           10  FILLER 
               OCCURS 0 TO 62 TIMES 
               DEPENDING ON 
               LENGTH-OF-USER-DATA. 
               15  FILLER                  PIC X. 
   01  EXPANDED-DIRECTORY. 
       05  E-D-NUMBER-OF-ENTRIES    BINARY PIC 9(4). 
       05  FILLER OCCURS 22 TIMES. 
           10  E-D-MEMBER-NAME             PIC X(8). 
           10  E-D-TRACK-ADDRESS           PIC X(3). 
           10  E-D-INDICATOR               PIC X(1). 
           10  E-D-ALIAS-FLAG              PIC X. 
               88  E-D-ALIAS               VALUE "Y". 
               88  E-D-ALIAS-NOT           VALUE "N". 
           10  E-D-NO-OF-POINTERS          PIC 9. 
           10  E-D-USER-DATA               PIC X(62). 
   PROCEDURE DIVISION               USING 
                                          INPUT-DIRECTORY 
                                          EXPANDED-DIRECTORY 
                                          . 

       IF I-D-NO-MEMBERS 
           MOVE ZERO                TO DIRECTORY-DATA-LENGTH 
       ELSE 
           SUBTRACT +2              FROM I-D-LENGTH 
             GIVING                 DIRECTORY-DATA-LENGTH 
       END-IF 

       MOVE ZERO                    TO E-D-NUMBER-OF-ENTRIES 
                                       LENGTH-UP-DIRECTORY 
       PERFORM UNTIL ( LENGTH-UP-DIRECTORY 
             NOT LESS THAN DIRECTORY-DATA-LENGTH ) 
                 OR ( I-D-END-OF-BLOCK ) 
           ADD 1                    TO E-D-NUMBER-OF-ENTRIES 
           MOVE I-D-MEMBER-NAME     TO E-D-MEMBER-NAME 
                                        ( E-D-NUMBER-OF-ENTRIES ) 
           MOVE I-D-TRACK-ADDRESS   TO E-D-TRACK-ADDRESS 
                                        ( E-D-NUMBER-OF-ENTRIES ) 
           MOVE I-D-INDICATOR       TO E-D-INDICATOR 
                                        ( E-D-NUMBER-OF-ENTRIES ) 
                                           USER-DATA-BYTE 
           MOVE ZERO                TO E-D-NO-OF-POINTERS 
                                        ( E-D-NUMBER-OF-ENTRIES ) 
           IF MEMBER-IS-AN-ALIAS 
               SET E-D-ALIAS ( E-D-NUMBER-OF-ENTRIES ) 
                                    TO TRUE 
               SUBTRACT HIGH-ORDER-BIT-VALUE 
                                    FROM USER-DATA-LENGTH 
           ELSE 
               SET E-D-ALIAS-NOT ( E-D-NUMBER-OF-ENTRIES ) 
                                    TO TRUE 
           END-IF 
           IF MEMBER-HAS-TWO-POINTERS 
               MOVE 2               TO E-D-NO-OF-POINTERS 
                                        ( E-D-NUMBER-OF-ENTRIES )
               SUBTRACT BIT-ONE-VALUE 
                                    FROM USER-DATA-LENGTH 
           END-IF 
           IF MEMBER-HAS-ONE-POINTER 
               ADD 1                TO E-D-NO-OF-POINTERS 
                                        ( E-D-NUMBER-OF-ENTRIES )
               SUBTRACT BIT-TWO-VALUE 
                                    FROM USER-DATA-LENGTH 
           END-IF 
           IF SOME-USER-HALFWORDS 
               MULTIPLY USER-DATA-LENGTH BY 2 
                GIVING              LENGTH-OF-USER-DATA 
               MOVE I-D-USER-DATA   TO E-D-USER-DATA 
                                        ( E-D-NUMBER-OF-ENTRIES )
               ADD LENGTH-OF-USER-DATA TO LENGTH-UP-DIRECTORY 
           ELSE 
               MOVE SPACE           TO E-D-USER-DATA 
                                        ( E-D-NUMBER-OF-ENTRIES )
               MOVE ZERO            TO LENGTH-OF-USER-DATA 
           END-IF 
           ADD 12                   TO LENGTH-UP-DIRECTORY 
       END-PERFORM 
       GOBACK 
       .
```

Here's an example of a program reading a PDS/PDSE directory, and using OCDIRBLK as a contained/nested/embedded program.

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION. 
   PROGRAM-ID. STOB30. 
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION. 
   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION. 
   FILE-CONTROL. 

        SELECT INPUT-FILE ASSIGN TO PDSIND 
           FILE STATUS IS W-PDSIND-FILE-STATUS. 

   DATA DIVISION. 
   FILE SECTION. 
   FD         INPUT-FILE 
       RECORDING MODE IS U 
       RECORD IS VARYING FROM 1 TO 256 DEPENDING ON 
       W-RECORD-LENGTH 
       LABEL RECORDS ARE STANDARD. 
   01  INPUT-RECORD. 
       05  FILLER PIC X(252). 
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION. 
   01  W-THIS-PROGRAM                      PIC X(9) VALUE 
                                                     "STOB30".
   01  W-WHEN-COMPILED                     PIC X(8)BX(8). 
   01  W-RECORD-LENGTH              BINARY PIC 9(8). 
   01  W-PDSIND-FILE-STATUS                PIC XX. 
       88  W-PDSIND-FILE-STATUS-OK         VALUE ZERO "10". 
       88  W-END-OF-INPUT-PDSIND           VALUE "10". 
   01  EXPANDED-DIRECTORY. 
       05  E-D-NUMBER-OF-ENTRIES    BINARY PIC 9(4). 
       05  FILLER 
           OCCURS 22 TIMES 
           INDEXED BY E-D-IND. 
           10  E-D-MEMBER-NAME             PIC X(8). 
           10  E-D-TRACK-ADDRESS           PIC X(3). 
           10  E-D-INDICATOR               PIC X(1). 
           10  E-D-ALIAS-FLAG              PIC X. 
               88  E-D-ALIAS               VALUE "Y". 
               88  E-D-ALIAS-NOT           VALUE "N". 
           10  E-D-NO-OF-POINTERS          PIC 9. 
           10  E-D-USER-DATA               PIC X(62). 
   PROCEDURE DIVISION. 
       PERFORM                      00-START-UP 
       PERFORM                      10-INTIAL-FILE-PROCESSING 
       PERFORM UNTIL W-END-OF-INPUT-PDSIND 
           CALL "OCDIRBLK"          USING INPUT-RECORD 
                                          EXPANDED-DIRECTORY 
           SET E-D-IND              TO 1 
           PERFORM E-D-NUMBER-OF-ENTRIES TIMES 
              DISPLAY 
                      E-D-MEMBER-NAME ( E-D-IND ) 
              SET E-D-IND           UP BY 1 
           END-PERFORM 
           PERFORM                  99A-READ-INPUT-FILE 
       END-PERFORM 
       PERFORM                      30-FINALISE-INPUT-PROCESSING
       GOBACK 
       . 
   00-START-UP. 
       MOVE WHEN-COMPILED           TO W-WHEN-COMPILED 
       DISPLAY 
               W-THIS-PROGRAM 
               " COMPILED ON " 
               W-WHEN-COMPILED 
       . 
   10-INTIAL-FILE-PROCESSING. 
       OPEN INPUT INPUT-FILE 
       IF NOT W-PDSIND-FILE-STATUS-OK 
           DISPLAY W-THIS-PROGRAM " DODGY PDSIND OPEN STATUS " 
                   ">" W-PDSIND-FILE-STATUS "<" 
           CALL "BBDUMP" 
       END-IF 

       PERFORM                      10A-PRIMING-READ 
       . 
   10A-PRIMING-READ. 
       PERFORM                      99A-READ-INPUT-FILE 
       . 
   30-FINALISE-INPUT-PROCESSING. 
       CLOSE INPUT-FILE 
       IF NOT W-PDSIND-FILE-STATUS-OK 
           DISPLAY W-THIS-PROGRAM " DODGY PDSIND CLOSE STATUS "
                   ">" W-PDSIND-FILE-STATUS "<" 
           CALL "BBDUMP" 
       END-IF 
       . 
   99A-READ-INPUT-FILE. 
       IF  W-END-OF-INPUT-PDSIND 
            DISPLAY "YOIKS" 
       END-IF 
       READ INPUT-FILE 
       IF NOT W-PDSIND-FILE-STATUS-OK 
           DISPLAY W-THIS-PROGRAM " DODGY PDSIND READ " 
                   ">" W-PDSIND-FILE-STATUS "<" 
           CALL "BBDUMP" 
       END-IF 
       . 
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION. 
   PROGRAM-ID. OCDIRBLK. 
   DATA DIVISION. 
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION. 
   01  LENGTH-UP-DIRECTORY          BINARY PIC 9(4). 
   01  LENGTH-OF-USER-DATA          BINARY PIC 9(4). 
   01  DIRECTORY-DATA-LENGTH        BINARY PIC 9(4). 
   01  HIGH-ORDER-BIT-VALUE         BINARY PIC 9(4) VALUE 128. 
   01  BIT-ONE-VALUE                BINARY PIC 9(4) VALUE 64. 
   01  BIT-TWO-VALUE                BINARY PIC 9(4) VALUE 32. 
   01  USER-DATA-LENGTH             BINARY PIC 9(4). 
       88  NO-USER-HALFWORDS               VALUE ZERO. 
       88  SOME-USER-HALFWORDS             VALUE 1 THRU 31. 
       88  MEMBER-HAS-ONE-POINTER          VALUE 32 THRU 63. 
       88  MEMBER-HAS-TWO-POINTERS         VALUE 64 THRU 127. 
       88  MEMBER-IS-AN-ALIAS              VALUE 128 THRU 255. 
   01  FILLER REDEFINES USER-DATA-LENGTH. 
       05  FILLER                          PIC X. 
       05  USER-DATA-BYTE                  PIC X. 
   LINKAGE SECTION. 
   01  INPUT-DIRECTORY. 
       05  I-D-LENGTH               BINARY PIC 9(4). 
           88  I-D-NO-MEMBERS              VALUE ZERO. 
       05  FILLER OCCURS 0 TO 252 TIMES 
           DEPENDING ON LENGTH-UP-DIRECTORY 
                                           PIC X. 
       05  I-D-MEMBER-NAME                 PIC X(8). 
           88 I-D-END-OF-BLOCK             VALUE HIGH-VALUES.
       05  I-D-TRACK-ADDRESS               PIC XXX. 
       05  I-D-INDICATOR                   PIC X. 
       05  I-D-USER-DATA. 
           10  FILLER 
               OCCURS 0 TO 62 TIMES 
               DEPENDING ON 
               LENGTH-OF-USER-DATA. 
               15  FILLER                  PIC X. 
   01  EXPANDED-DIRECTORY. 
       05  E-D-NUMBER-OF-ENTRIES    BINARY PIC 9(4). 
       05  FILLER OCCURS 22 TIMES. 
           10  E-D-MEMBER-NAME             PIC X(8). 
           10  E-D-TRACK-ADDRESS           PIC X(3). 
           10  E-D-INDICATOR               PIC X(1). 
           10  E-D-ALIAS-FLAG              PIC X. 
               88  E-D-ALIAS               VALUE "Y". 
               88  E-D-ALIAS-NOT           VALUE "N". 
           10  E-D-NO-OF-POINTERS          PIC 9. 
           10  E-D-USER-DATA               PIC X(62). 
   PROCEDURE DIVISION               USING 
                                          INPUT-DIRECTORY 
                                          EXPANDED-DIRECTORY 
                                          . 

       IF I-D-NO-MEMBERS 
           MOVE ZERO                TO DIRECTORY-DATA-LENGTH 
       ELSE 
           SUBTRACT +2              FROM I-D-LENGTH 
             GIVING                 DIRECTORY-DATA-LENGTH 
       END-IF 

       MOVE ZERO                    TO E-D-NUMBER-OF-ENTRIES 
                                       LENGTH-UP-DIRECTORY 
       PERFORM UNTIL ( LENGTH-UP-DIRECTORY 
             NOT LESS THAN DIRECTORY-DATA-LENGTH ) 
                 OR ( I-D-END-OF-BLOCK ) 
           ADD 1                    TO E-D-NUMBER-OF-ENTRIES 
           MOVE I-D-MEMBER-NAME     TO E-D-MEMBER-NAME 
                                        ( E-D-NUMBER-OF-ENTRIES )
           MOVE I-D-TRACK-ADDRESS   TO E-D-TRACK-ADDRESS 
                                        ( E-D-NUMBER-OF-ENTRIES )
           MOVE I-D-INDICATOR       TO E-D-INDICATOR 
                                        ( E-D-NUMBER-OF-ENTRIES )
                                           USER-DATA-BYTE 
           MOVE ZERO                TO E-D-NO-OF-POINTERS 
                                        ( E-D-NUMBER-OF-ENTRIES )
           IF MEMBER-IS-AN-ALIAS 
               SET E-D-ALIAS ( E-D-NUMBER-OF-ENTRIES ) 
                                    TO TRUE 
               SUBTRACT HIGH-ORDER-BIT-VALUE 
                                    FROM USER-DATA-LENGTH 
           ELSE 
               SET E-D-ALIAS-NOT ( E-D-NUMBER-OF-ENTRIES ) 
                                    TO TRUE 
           END-IF 
           IF MEMBER-HAS-TWO-POINTERS 
               MOVE 2               TO E-D-NO-OF-POINTERS 
                                        ( E-D-NUMBER-OF-ENTRIES )
               SUBTRACT BIT-ONE-VALUE 
                                    FROM USER-DATA-LENGTH 
           END-IF 
           IF MEMBER-HAS-ONE-POINTER 
               ADD 1                TO E-D-NO-OF-POINTERS 
                                        ( E-D-NUMBER-OF-ENTRIES )
               SUBTRACT BIT-TWO-VALUE 
                                    FROM USER-DATA-LENGTH 
           END-IF 
           IF SOME-USER-HALFWORDS 
               MULTIPLY USER-DATA-LENGTH BY 2 
                GIVING              LENGTH-OF-USER-DATA 
               MOVE I-D-USER-DATA   TO E-D-USER-DATA 
                                        ( E-D-NUMBER-OF-ENTRIES )
               ADD LENGTH-OF-USER-DATA TO LENGTH-UP-DIRECTORY 
           ELSE 
               MOVE SPACE           TO E-D-USER-DATA 
                                        ( E-D-NUMBER-OF-ENTRIES )
               MOVE ZERO            TO LENGTH-OF-USER-DATA 
           END-IF 
           ADD 12                   TO LENGTH-UP-DIRECTORY 
       END-PERFORM 
       GOBACK 
       . 
   END PROGRAM OCDIRBLK. 
   END PROGRAM STOB30.
```

Here's an example of the JCL:

```
//LISTDIR EXEC PGM=STOB30,TIME=(,2)
//STEPLIB DD DSN=yours as necessary
//SYSOUT DD SYSOUT=* for the DISPLAY output 
//PDSIND DD DSN=your pds/pdse,
// DISP=SHR,LRECL=256,RECFM=U
```

Note, whilst setting up the JCL I didn't include the RECFM=U (by accident). Ran clean producing the correct results with a RECFM=FB,LRECL=80 PDS and a RECFM=U PDSE.

This surprised me. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Shouldn't that be 255, not 252? IIRC, PDS directory records are an 8-byte key (CKD) followed by up to 255 bytes. (The key isn't presented for the I/O.)

Comment: @zarchasmpgmr possibly 256. I may be getting away with it by using U. I only recently discovered that F was possible, and there I'd guess I have to get the length correct.

Comment: It is 256. Remember the old trick to print the directory in IEBPTPCH? RECFM=U,BLKSIZE=256,KEYLEN=8

Comment: I see what I did. In the CALLing program I had `RECORD IS VARYING FROM 1 TO 256 DEPENDING ON W-RECORD-LENGTH` and since the length is not relevant for the CALLed program, I chopped it without checking. I use LRECL=256, didn't ever think about the BLKSIZE. I don't think it needs the KEYLEN (I've never used it). I'll look at PTPCH for this, I would have used GENER, although I like PTPCH for many things :-) ) 
`

Comment: There may be some newer (and by newer I mean 1980s ;) ) assists for reading the directory. The DCB trick used to be documented in the Utilities manual. It might have been for GENER rather than PTPCH.

So many overlooked things in the Utilities manuals. IEBEDIT and IEBDG have some nice hacks beyond their supposed functions.

Comment: The solution works for input  PDSs with record length 256, what about a typical text pds record length 80?

Comment: The 256 relates to the directory blocks for the PDS, which are the same, no matter what the LRECL which is used for the members on the PDS. It should work with a source PDS and with a loadlibrary. If it doesn't, let me know what happens, it'll be an easy fix.

Comment: That works perfectly for a dataset with record length=232. When I try that for a dataset of record length 80, Fixed format(F) with following attribute specification in JCL, LRECL=80, RECFM=F, filestatus code 90 is got after file open. If I specify RECFM=U in JCL, then it runs, but the member names are NOT correct, e.g. first member=A , second=B1, third= K=PLAYGR(not correct), remaining member names are empty.

Comment: Did you specify the PDS *in the JCL* as RECFM=U and LRECL=256? That will work with any PDS irrespective of the RECFM and LRECL of the members of the PDS. If that does not work, post the JCL and the FD you have for the COBOL program in your question,

Comment: JCL  
    //STEP1      EXEC    PGM=XXX
    //INPUTDS    DD DISP=SHR,DSN=DSN80,RECFM=U

Comment: You need the LRECL=256 on the `//INPUTDS DD`

Comment: It is a "con" which allows you to read the directory blocks. You can't access the data this way, nor by just specifying the PDS-name.

Comment: Yes , I tried that as well, but still the error. Note that calling program uses        `FD  INPUT-FILE
            RECORDING MODE IS U
            LABEL RECORDS ARE STANDARD.
        01  INPUT-RECORD.
            05  FILLER             PIC X(80).`

Comment: call is as follows:   `              MOVE INPUT-RECORD        TO WRK-IN-RECORD
               CALL "OCDIRBLK" USING  WRK-RECORD
                                      EXPANDED-DIRECTORY`

Comment: Change that `PIC X(80)` to `PIC X(256)`. You are not accessing the data, but the directory blocks. By coding like that you have truncated the directory blocks, and chaos will ensue. If you use INPUT-RECORD on the CALL, you may get away with it. Unclear what the relationship between WRK-IN-RECORD and WRK-RECORD is. Typo putting it here?

Comment: @cobp I've included a sample calling program now.

Comment: It is working, the problem was the the X(80) record definition. Thanks.

Comment: Two picky comments...first, LRECL is pretty much meaningless for RECFM=U - it's BLKSIZE that counts, and that's pretty much an upper limit rather than an actual value. Number two is that you might want to test carefully with concatenated inputs and PDSE datasets if the alphabetic sequence of member names is important (as well as possibility of duplicates, etc).

Comment: @ValerieR Well, I've never thought of doing it on a concatenation. Have to try that now. Don't see why it wouldn't work. I'm fairly sure I've done it to PDSEs, but will confirm. Since the need is a list to do something else with the order doesn't matter. Not sure about how meaningless LRECL vs BLKSIZE is for RECFM=U. It's just blobs of data. Some experiments needed :-)

Comment: @ValerieR If I don't specify an LRECL equal to what my COBOL program expects, the first concatenation takes "it's own" LRECL. Since the directory records are 256, an 80-byte length would just chop up the data, badly. Concatenated plain 80-byte, loadlib and PDSE with executable programs together, no problems encountered with duplicate member names (they are just part of the directory entries) or sequence of those in the PDSEs.

Comment: @Bill: on my system (which admittedly might be different than yours), COBOL opening a REFCM U file does a BSAM OPEN/J, and so long as I specify a BLKSIZE at least as big as the largest directory block (256 is safe), your app runs fine with no LRECL at all. The directory has a legitimate EOF mark, so BSAM EOV processing steps through all the concatenated files just fine - my point was that it's sometimes surprising when you see members not in alphabetic sequence or duplicate names...this is where concatenation is the culprit...not broken, just unexpected.

Comment: One other small point...those looking for a more modern and less "hackish" way to read PDS/PDSE directory blocks might also be interested to know that you can use C-style opendir() and readdir() to access PDS directories. In COBOL, you can call the BPX1... callable services, or opendir()/readdir() directly from the runtime library.

Comment: @ValerieR That would be much better :-)